# Query on parse user table not working

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

```
ParseQuery query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
@override
public void done(List list, ParseException e) {
}
}
```

`findInBackground` showing error c`om.parse.ParseRequest: Request failed.`
it is showing the error even without where conditions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my query.
Looks like yours has some errors.

This is getting a specific user

```
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryUserByID = ParseUser.getQuery();
        queryUserByID.getInBackground(userObjectID, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    //good
                } else {
                    //error
                }
            }
        });
```

This is for the list of users.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //good
            } else {
                //error
            }
        }
    });
```